# Sitefinity Thunder Connection String Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity, sitefinity-5

Every Time i tried to connect my sitefinity Project to thunder it gives me error "Unable to connect"

Comment: Are you willing to use feather widgets?

Comment: @JonR. yes but how can i make my custom widget on feather .. there is only sitefinity custom widget for feather in resource package ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a custom MVC widget you would scaffold an MVC widget as normal.  To get it to show up in the Toolbox you need to decorate the controller with this:

`[ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "Features", Title = "Features", SectionName = "MVC")]`

Here is a help article.
https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-create-mvc-based-sitefinity-widgets

If the default Visual Studio MVC scaffolding is not working on your project try this article, it's a little outdated but might still apply:

http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/peter-marinovs-blog/2014/02/27/how-to-add-the-visual-studio-mvc-features-for-a-sitefinity-project